# php if isset post and else post

Tags: php, html

I have html form with 2 buttons 'OK' and 'Cancel'
to get first one I do:

```
if (isset($_POST['submit']))
{
```

but how to use 'Cancel', so when I will click it it will redirect me to another page?

Comment: if your button name is `cancel` then you can check if `$_POST['cancel']` is set

Comment: it's after first if {?, or it's }else{

Comment: If the cancel button is pressed then `submit` will not be set.

Comment: You should really be handling cancel on the client side, with javascript. If they are cancelling, you really shouldn't be sending a needless html request. When the page loads initially, you should be loading the conditions for a possible cancel into javascript.

Comment: @GaryHayes there is no javascript

Comment: If there is no javascript, then you can have the submit button on one form, and the cancel button ( using submit ) on another form. Still no need to needlessly send requests to server side.

Comment: @GaryHayes, I understand, maybe what you said is more correct.. but I need what was asked in question. If I click 'Ok' it will do what he needs to do, else, if 'Cancel', it will redirect me to my main page

Comment: _“but how to use 'Cancel', so when I will click it it will redirect me to another page?”_ - by using a simple _link_ to that other page …? Makes very little sense to actually submit the form first in the scenario you described.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like:

```
if (isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    // do something here
} 
elseif (isset($_POST['cancel']))
{
    // redirect here
}
```

Comment: Thx, that's exact answer that I needed

Comment: in 4 minutes :)